# Save php file into variable

Tags: php

I am trying to get the contents of an included PHP file, for example:

**PHP**

```
$body = include 'body.php';
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What's in body.php? Do you `return` something?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you mean to output the PHP code on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Output Buffer it to make sure the HTML isn't shown and is instead put into a variable. (PHP will still run, but HTML output will be contained in the variable)
You can save in a variable the contents of the output buffer using the function [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-get-contents.php).

**PHP**

```
ob_start();
include "body.php";
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thx sir, that's works, that's exactly what i needed !!

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include 'desired_file.php';
$file = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to have a return statement in your included file (body.php).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's true. If you `$body = (include "body.php");` and have a return in body it will work.

Comment: return statement should be used inside functions. Although it can be used outside function scope, it is pointless, just because of ob_get_contents, ob_end_clean. That's why it is downvoted.

Comment: ```return``` statement is not only for inside functions. If it was it wouldn't be available outside of a function. You can put a return statement inside a file so that you can behave that file like a function. This statement is being used in many places. You can find it even in Laravel framework codes. (For language feature, check it out).

Comment: Cool. That's exactly why I don't use Laravel or any modern framework. :) If anything is worth saving Your time, that would be the Phalcon fw https://phalconphp.com/en/.

Comment: I do usually use CodeIgniter for my personal projects. I have worked with Phalcon, CakePHP and laravel too. I think laravel is one of the bests for large scale projects. Laravel's community is very large and I think the opinion of such community is much more important than one, like you.